# Kubernetes access labels from containers

Tags: docker, kubernetes

When we create a yml for the replication controller, we can give labels for the pod that is being created.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
        tier: backend
```

Can the containers that reside in this pod access those label values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [Downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/), which allows the container to know more about itself.

Comment: the link is broken. This is especially bad, since you write next to nothing about how it works, but instead rely completely on the contents of that link.

Comment: I guess this may be relevant: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#capabilities-of-the-downward-api

Answer (score 1):

One way to access information of pod from inside the container is by using environment variables. The yaml file for pod is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod-env
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: ubuntu
      command: [ "sh", "-c"]
      args:
      - while true; do
          echo -en '\n';
          printenv MY_NODE_NAME MY_POD_NAME;
          printenv MY_POD_IP 
          sleep 1000;
        done;
      env:
        - name: MY_NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        - name: MY_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: MY_POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
  restartPolicy: Never
```

The mY_POD_NAME environment variable gets its value from the pod's field spec.nodeName. Likewise we can also container's fields as values. 
To verify this connect to the pod using the command:

```
kubectl exec -it pod-env -- /bin/bash
```

and print the environment variable:

```
printenv MY_POD_NAME
```

Other way of passing information from pod to container is using downwardAPI : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/